# Init Ilist in a automapper in the same line

Tags: c#, list, automapper

I seem to have some issue init a IList defined in a class, using automapper, and then adding a element to this list.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(.ForMember(dest => dest.Catalogs = new List<dto>);
```

can this not be done in the same line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you should note is that AutoMapper will create collections automatically if it kowns how to map the elements of these collections.

For example, given the following classes:

```
public class Source {
    public IList<SourceObj> SourceCollection {get; set;}
}

public class Destination {
    public DestDto[] DestinationCollection {get; set;}
}
```

The collections will be mapped correctly with this configuration:

```
CreateMap<SourceObj, DestDto>();

CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DestinationCollection, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SourceCollection));
```

Check if this mapping works:

```
var destDto = Mapper.Map<Destination>(sourceObj);
Assert.IsNotNull(destDto.DestinationCollection);
```

If you always want to set the destination collection to an empty list, you can do that with `ResolveUsing`:

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DestinationCollection, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => new List<DestDto>()));
```